# iOS how can I remove 'App link' button from the status bar when open app via deeplink?

Tags: ios, deep-linking

When I open the app via Branch deeplink there emerges app link button on the upper right corner on status bar that allows you to block app links. So that all the deeplinks start to redirect me to Appstore.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1vmQ.png)

Can I remove this button somehow?

Because common users could accidentally press this button thereby blocking their deeplinking ability and the next time they'll be redirected to Appstore. And I think it's very unclear for them to resolve this issue.

Comment: No you can't do this, this is default behavior of iOS

Answer (score 0):

The button you seeing is the feature of iOS Universal Links. You can't disable this button.